# Displaying PDF to Browser with PHP not working

Tags: php, pdf

Using php's ability to call upon the browser to display a given PDF it doesn't work on my web host. But it works on my local xamp server with apache.

**PHP:**

```
    $title = $_GET['title'];
    $loc = $_GET['loc'];

    header("Content-type: application/pdf");
    header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=".$title);
    @readfile($loc);
```

**Expected Output:** Supposed to be the PDF document being rendered like it does on my local web server.

**Actual but unwanted output:**
%PDF-1.6 %���� 1638 0 obj <> endobj xref 1638 44 0000000016 00000 n ...

Can be seen here:
http://neilau.me/view.php?title=business-studies-hsc-notes-2006.pdf&loc=pdf/criteria/business-studies/2006/business-studies-hsc-notes-2006.pdf

Is this fixed through changing something on my cpanel? As my code isn't faulty... It works on my local web server.

Comment: remove the @ before readfile, so you can get more error's details...

Comment: Well I visited that link and the response headers contain `Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8` so something must be overwriting them...

Comment: @Masiorama removed that, it is just a blank screen

Comment: @NeilD check out apokryfos comment, it will put you in the right path.

Comment: @apokryfos How to I stop it from overriding? Could you tell me what causes this. Cheers

Comment: If you're using a shared hosting service then you can first search their forums or their support questions.

Comment: @apokryfos I've asked them, but they are telling me to contact my developer? Haha, I don't think they understand. Hmmm, this is painful

Comment: @NeilD I suspect you're omitting some code you're not sharing. I only suspect this because your script is very insecure so anyone can inspect its source code by setting `loc=view.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure you are not sending **any text** before writing headers.

Example of what **not to do**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
...
<?php
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
```

Example of how to fix that:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: application/pdf");    
?>   
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
...
```

In addition your script is very insecure. Here's what you should do, your entire PHP script should be:

```
<?php
$loc = filter_input(INPUT_GET,"loc");
$title = filter_input(INPUT_GET,'title')?:basename($loc);
if (!is_readable($loc)) {
    http_response_code(404);
    echo "Cannot find that file";
    die();
}
if (strtolower(pathInfo($loc,PATHINFO_EXTENSION)) != "pdf") {
   http_response_code(403);
    echo "You are not allowed access to that file";
    die();
}

header("Content-type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=".$title);
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($loc));
readfile($loc);
```

If you want to show things like a page title or a frame around it, you should use an iframe in another "wrapper" page:

```
<?php 
$loc = filter_input(INPUT_GET,"loc");
$title = filter_input(INPUT_GET,'title')?:basename($loc);
?>
<html><head><title>My title</title></head>
<body>
<iframe src="/view.php?<?php echo ($loc?"loc=$loc":"").($title?"title=$title":"") ?>">
</iframe>
</body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this code

```
<?php
$file = 'dummy.pdf';
$filename = 'dummy.pdf';
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $filename . '"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
@readfile($file);
?>
```

Comment: Hi Palani, I've made my code the same as that however, as you can see on this link http://neilau.me/view.php?title=business-studies-hsc-notes-2006.pdf&loc=pdf/criteria/business-studies/2006/business-studies-hsc-notes-2006.pdf it is still being displayed in letters and symbols.